# Upload image doesn't change after refresh but change after save in text editor

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with my Angular4 app, I've made the whole upload file system and it's working but when i do upload the image and refresh the page, the image doesn"t change.

Here's the img tag

```
<img  class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="../../../assets/img/profile/{{user.img}}" width="300px" height="300px">
```

user.img is a string from the database.

The component file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl,FormGroup,FormBuilder,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { FileUploader ,FileSelectDirective} from 'ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-profile',
  templateUrl: './edit-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-profile.component.css']
})
export class EditProfileComponent implements OnInit {

 editForm;
  messageClass;
  message;
  user;
  birthday;
  bYear; // cut the date to fit the select tag
  bMonth;
  bDay;
  
  public uploader: FileUploader= new FileUploader({url:'http://localhost:8080/authentication/edit-photo',headers:[{name:'authorization',value:this.authService.authToken}]});

ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(data=>{
      this.user=data.user;
      this.birthday=new Date(this.user.birthday);
      this.bMonth=this.birthday.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      this.bYear=this.birthday.getUTCFullYear();
      this.bDay=this.birthday.getUTCDate();
      
    });
```

I've tried lot of ways, none of them has worked yet. What do you propose ?

**EDIT**

I've noticed that when i saved the file in the code editor, the image changes, but after refreshing the browser, it's not.

I also want to specify that all image uploaded are placed in the asset folder in the src folder of angular, because i could'nt access them when they were outside of the angular directory.
Maybe that's why it doesn't change before i save the file ? because the ng serve reload ? Please i need help for this

Comment: does it change on the server?

Comment: Does user.img change with new upload? If not, you may be hitting browser cache = you need unique image url for each upload

Comment: assuming your server can deal with it, add a random query string to the image URL so the browser won't get the image from its cache

Comment: @JaromandaX It does.

Comment: @insider I just console.logged user.img and I have a blank page ! There's a new error i must found here ..

Comment: user.img seems to be undefined as all the other attributes ? There's a weird error here. But they're still working on te template

Comment: @StephenThomas Can you be more specific ? That's weird because when i save the file in the code editor, the image change, but after refreshing the browser, it's not.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=random+query+string+cache+busting

Comment: @StephenThomas If by that you mean adding a unique key to each upload, I did it, but since angular doesn't know the file before i hit save in the text editor , it displays nothing. I need a way to start a ng serve everytime i upload a file, but I'm afraid it's gonna be bad for production

Comment: Please guys I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same kind of issue and it was cache problem.  I tested it in Ror&angular website.
For default the **image data cache** exists 2 days.
Have you once changed the image in your File explorer(Finder)?.
I have deleted the cache and it worked well.
If you don't want to delete cache, you can complete the code in **Incognito window** and test the final action after 2 days.

Comment: Sure but when in production, client is probably not going to be in incognito. I need a stable solution for this to move on, it's taking too much time now. About the cache, that's probably the problem however maybe it"s not. I was thinking about the fact that all angular files might be static before a ng serve, but probably related to the cache. I don't know how cache works with anglar2+, even the doc doesn"t talk about it.

Comment: @AzoulayJason the cache is handled by browser not by angular. If you want to get rid of it, you have few options: #1 set correct headers for image request (needs to be done on server). #2 set unique url for each upload so browser has still cache (= you save bandwidth for unchanged images)

Comment: I've followed your instruction. There was indeed a cookie at the name of the picture, so I removed cookie from the request headers, then i've set a unique id to each uploads. The result is that there's no picture displayed and I got an error 404 not finding the file. My guess is that angular doesn't even know the picture exist before I hit save button in my text editor.

Comment: I think I have to restart server everytime I upload a file, how can i do that ?
Is this a good process ?

Comment: You don't need that, In my experience , if I don't change the static file content in file explorer, all things worked well, reading and writing then reading.

Comment: @artgb Well not to me, and i didn't touch file content in file explorer.

Comment: You probably don"t care but this is becoming very frustrating to me, I couldn"t find any solution in DAYS, maybe you didn't understand the problem I'm facing but I need your help guys please help me

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `ng serve` as a production build, it uses a webpack dev-server which is only meant for development. You want to use `ng build` and serve the index.html file through nginx, apache, or some other server software. Here is a short forum on this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274

The webpack dev-server creates the build in your local virtual memory. So when you update your assets folder you have to restart ng serve so the webpack dev-server has the updated assets.

This won't be a problem when using `ng build` since both the application & the assets folder will be served on the same server.

Comment: Actually it's not a server compatibility problem, it's more like a compilation problem. Angular can't detect the file I've just uploaded since it's not in its "memory".It is embedded only after a `ng serve`, I've just tried a `ng build` and still has the same issue.

Comment: @AzoulayJason the more I think about it, I don't think assets is the best place for user images. Assets should contain files that are only added when you are releasing new versions. I would add the images outside of your angular directory and reference them with a full url